# Why did the DNC try to prevent Bernie Sanders from getting the Democratic nomination?

Tags: united-states, election, parties, bernie-sanders, dnc

I recently read a few news articles talking about a [class action lawsuit](http://www.newsweek.com/bernie-sanders-rigged-hillary-clinton-dnc-lawsuit-donald-trump-president-609582) against the DNC for cheating Bernie Sanders out of the primaries. Is there any truth to these claims that there were concerted efforts of Democratic politicians and the establishment to rig the primary for Hillary Clinton? If there is evidence that the DNC colluded against Bernie, why the heck would they do that?

My reason for asking is just that I think Bernie would have been a better opponent than Hillary was in the election and I am confused about why the DNC would side with one candidate if they did, in fact, do so.

One other article on [Snopes](http://www.snopes.com/2016/07/25/what-we-know-so-far-about-wikileaks-dncleaks/) had some info about all this too, but I don't feel like they provided any definitive answers that I was looking for. Here is the tweet that WikiLeaks sent out with a summary of the claims:

[image: DNC emails]

Comment: "Is there any truth ...? If there is ... why ...?" These are two questions posed in one and the second is even conditioned on the outcome of the first one. I strongly recommend asking them sequentially. This should give much better Q&A in the end.

Comment: I think the edit makes this even more pure speculation.

Comment: Honestly, I think this question is a fantastic example of why a politics StackExchange doesn't make sense.  Politics is a land of argument, not one of clear questions or answers.  One of the two top voted answers to this question is attempting to refute the premise of it -- but leans heavily on opinion sources making arguments.  It's literally impossible to determine what the true facts are in this matter.  We cannot know what was in the heads of the people in the DNC.  We cannot truly isolate the impact of their actions from the complex system that is politics.  It's impossible to answer this

Comment: The title was edited to make the question less inflammatory.  The question can be answered just the same without the edit.  Also, please try to leave your personal opinions out of the question if they're not crucial for someone to be able to answer it.

Comment: So because you disagree with my opinion you can strip my question of most of its context in regards to why I asked it and drastically change the core meaning of the title? I can maybe understand the reasoning behind removing the edit even though I think it was necessary, but every single one of the posted answers was posted under "Why did the DNC try" question title. I guess I will leave the question the way you want it instead of the way I meant to ask it if that is how this site is run...

Comment: After reviewing the guidelines on editing posts I decided to roll back to my original version considering the edits by Sam-I-am were flawed and biased since they changed the meaning of the question in my mind.

Comment: I locked the question due to a rollback war. I decided to lock it to a revision which doesn't make unproven accusations.

Comment: The ongoing edit wars, especially by the author, let me believe that the question is not asked in good faith. If the author would really be interested in possible motives, the altered title would make no difference. As it is, it seems that not the answer is important, but the question should work as a statement itself. Thus I am voting to close.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

In short, because Democratic Party in USA is roughly split between two factions (I'll label them "progressive" and "establishment" just for the sake of labeling).

[FiveThirtyEight covered this split in great detail in the last couple of months](https://fivethirtyeight.com/tag/party-time/) (as well as a split in Republican party); but for the purposes of this question, Sanders represented the "progressive" wing and Clinton "established" wing.

DNC leadership from what I understand is largely "established" wing and as such preferred Clinton to Sanders. Why? That could be for a variety of reasons:

- pragmatic politics (they could have thought that an establishment candidate has a better chance in general election, which is more or less the mainstream theory in Political Science since (e.g. [**Median Voter Theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_voter_theorem)) at the very least McGovern's drastic loss and a reason for DNC superdelegates).
- ideology. They simply agree with Clinton's ideas more than Sanders
- somewhat related, or correllated, tribalism - Sanders "isn't a real democrat!". As a reminder, he technically wasn't - he was a self-described Socialist (technically elected as Independent) as far as party membership in Congress.

  > "Spoken like someone who has never been a member of the Democratic Party and has no understanding of what we do," (*from DNC email dump*)
- conservatism (as a psychological trait, not political philosophy). Sanders' brand of firebrand populism may not necessarily sit well with powerful establishment, who would prefer not to rock the boat too much as it could affect their own position.
- identity politics. Clinton was the female candidate, in the minds of some people preferable to any male candidate regardless of other considerations (ironically, those people would probably more naturally belong to progressive wing of DNC, but them's the breaks - I vaguely recall 538 reporting that something like 90% of women of color voted for Clinton).
- power politics. The Clintons represent a big power center; and people often support such power centers to benefit themselves. Or, people owed favors to Clintons, which is in the same general bucket.
- "her turn". While I'm unsure of how popular the concept was, there definitely people who felt that running strong in 2008 primaries "entitled" Clinton to a turn at the wheel.

P.S. As an aside, the question's current phrasing makes an assumption that DNC ***prevented*** Sanders from getting the nomination. While this answer presents the plausible reasons for DNC to want to do so, I'm not actually aware of any ironclad proof that - despite some obvious efforts - DNC actually succeeded in that even assuming they uniformly wanted this (in other words, there needs to be tangible proof that without DNC efforts, Sanders would have won to make the assumption). [538 seems to have disagreed even early in the primaries](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/hillary-clintons-got-this/). As well as [much later](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/hillary-clinton-clinches-democratic-nomination-according-to-ap/).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion. This conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67311/discussion-on-answer-by-user4012-why-did-the-dnc-try-to-prevent-bernie-sanders-f).

Comment: Another possible reason (if it's true) is donations -- Clinton was getting money from some rather deep pockets (eg, new york bankers) that Sanders was talking about needing to regulate more.  If Sanders was elected, it's possible that they feared those donations would dry up as Sanders pushed the policies that he talked about on the campaign trail that would redude the profitability of some companies.  (this could fit under a few of the headings you have)

Comment: Please respect the move to chat. I deleted several comments reiterating point already discussed in the chatroom.

Comment: @Philipp: Please recognize that chat is non-functional (at least in some browsers), so "move to chat" translates as "I don't want you folks to keep discussing this", the more so as it appears to be used to censor "politically incorrect comments.

Comment: @jamesqf The chatroom works fine for me.

Comment: This site is ruined by terrible, biased moderators like Philipp and Sam. They alter questions and delete comments that do not fit their biased political agenda.

Comment: @mich to the best of my awareness these two specific moderators are from differing political positions. ;)

Comment: This answer would be better if it prominently mentioned that the DNC is a private organization with ZERO obligation to be neutral or to wait until any certain time before throwing their weight behind whoever the hell they want. People seem to not get that.

Comment: @WakeDemons3 - frankly, I assume it's obvious. But feel free to edit that in as one of 2 last paragraphs, I don't object.

Comment: @user4012, you pay more attention than I do. I've never been able to guess Sam's personal politics.

Comment: @grovkin - he stated it in either one of the answers or comments, so it's public info.

Comment: In an arguement for Pragmatic reasons, it should be noted that in the modern American political climate, more citizens identify as politically independent (slightly more than a full 1/3 of the population) than those that identify as either a democrat or a republican (both slightly less).  The general idea is that while they all are unique in what is a winning argument to win their vote is, they are more likely to switch between parties, they will favor the more moderate candidate.  Since socialism has never been widely accepted in the US, to the Dems in 2016, Hilary was the moderate choice.

Answer (score 66):

## The idea that the DNC "rigged" the primaries is false.

I voted Bernie in the primary, too, but it is very important not to take the claim in the WikiLeaks graphic at face value.

This July 2016 New Republic article debunks the claim: **[No, the DNC Didn’t Rig the Primary in Favor of Hillary](https://newrepublic.com/article/135472/no-dnc-didnt-rig-primary-favor-hillary)**:

> Wikileaks’s tweets conjured dark and menacing conspiracies, but these are not borne out by the emails themselves. Take the group’s claim that the “DNC knew of Hillary paid troll factory attacking Sanders online.” The highlighted email isn’t some secret communication laying out nefarious plots. It’s a summary of a panel discussion on Fox News Sunday.
>
> But forget the emails for a second. The main problem with the notion that the DNC rigged the results for Clinton is that it requires one to assume the improbable. The DNC had no role or authority in primary contests, which are run by state governments. Clinton dominated the primaries. The DNC, through state parties, had a bit more influence over caucuses … where Sanders dominated Clinton.
>
> None of the thousands of leaked emails and documents show the DNC significantly influencing the results of the nomination. Furthermore, if it is true that last fall Clinton campaign chair John Podesta tried but failed to have DNC Chair Debbie Wasserman Schultz sacked, the underlying premise of the entire WikiLeaks dump—that Wasserman Schultz machinated to deliver Clinton the nomination—is hard to believe.

See also Kurt Eichenwald's fiery but comprehensive Newsweek article, **[The Myths Democrats Swallowed That Cost Them the Presidential Election](http://www.newsweek.com/myths-cost-democrats-presidential-election-521044)**:

> Almost every email that set off the “rigged” accusations was from May 2016. (One was in late April; I’ll address that below.) Even in the most ridiculous of dream worlds, **Sanders could not have possibly won the nomination after May 3**—at that point, he needed 984 more pledged delegates, but there were only 933 available in the remaining contests. And political pros could tell by the delegate math that the race was over on April 19, since a victory would require him to win almost every single delegate after that, something no rational person could believe.

In other words, the emails were supportive of the at-that-time mathematically-certain Democratic nominee, Hillary Clinton. Eichenwald continues:

> Once only one candidate can win the nomination, *of course* the DNC gets to work on that person’s behalf. *Of course* emails from that time would reflect support for the person who would clearly be the nominee. And given that their jobs are to elect Democrats, *of course* DNC officials were annoyed that Sanders would not tell his followers he could not possibly be the nominee. Battling for the sake of battling gave his supporters a false belief that they could still win—something that added to their increasingly embittered feelings.

He concludes:

> Bottom line: The “scandalous” DNC emails were hacked by people working with the Kremlin, then misrepresented online by Russian propagandists to gullible fools who never checked the dates of the documents. And the media, which in the flurry of breathless stories about the emails would occasionally mention that they were all dated after any rational person knew the nomination was Clinton’s, fed into the misinformation.
>
> In the real world, here is what happened: Clinton got 16.9 million votes in the primaries, compared with 13.2 million for Sanders. The rules were never changed to stop him, even though Sanders supporters started calling for them to be changed as his losses piled up.

In a detailed state-by-state analysis, FiveThirtyEight declared (at the time) that [The System isn't Rigged Against Sanders](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/the-system-isnt-rigged-against-sanders/):

> Realistically, if you throw everything together, the math suggests that Sanders doesn’t have much to complain about. If the Democratic nomination were open to as many *Democrats* as possible — through closed primaries — Clinton would be dominating Sanders. And if the nomination were open to as many *voters* as possible — through open primaries — she’d still be winning.

One important point, mentioned also by some of the articles above:

## The DNC conspiracy claim was Russian propaganda, picked up by Bernie supporters, and later by Trump supporters

**[US Officials Say They Have Proof Russia Provided WikiLeaks with Hacked DNC Emails](https://www.vice.com/en_us/article/vvdwb4/us-officials-say-they-have-proof-russia-provided-wikileaks-with-hacked-dnc-emails-vgtrn)**:

> Three US officials confirmed this week that the intelligence community had conclusive evidence after the election that Russian cybercriminals provided WkiLeaks with hacked information from the DNC, reuters reports.

The timing of the release of these emails, the night before the Democratic National Convention, was clearly planned for maximum damage to the party.

[Bernie's campaign manager even supported the narrative](http://abcnews.go.com/Politics/bernie-sanders-campaign-chief-accountable-dnc-emails-show/story?id=40825318):

> Weaver said the emails showed misconduct at the highest level of the staff within the party and that he believed there would be more emails leaked, which would "reinforce" that the party had "its fingers on the scale."

Later in the general election, Trump picked up on the claim and used it against Clinton ([one tweet of many to choose from](http://abcnews.go.com/Politics/donald-trump-things-rigged-rigged/story?id=42738506)):

> President Obama should ask the DNC about how they rigged the election against Bernie.

This narrative was reinforced by [Russian Twitter bots and fake Facebook personas](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/09/07/us/politics/russia-facebook-twitter-election.html):

> An investigation by The New York Times, and new research from the cybersecurity firm FireEye, reveals some of the mechanisms by which suspected Russian operators used Twitter and Facebook to spread anti-Clinton messages and promote the hacked material they had leaked. On Wednesday, Facebook officials disclosed that they had shut down several hundred accounts that they believe were created by a Russian company linked to the Kremlin and used to buy $100,000 in ads pushing divisive issues during and after the American election campaign.

The New York Times article continues, detailing the focus these (suspected) Russian sources had on the "corrupt Hillary" narrative:

> Several activists who ran Facebook pages for Bernie Sanders, for instance, noticed a suspicious flood of hostile comments about Mrs. Clinton after Mr. Sanders had already ended his campaign and endorsed her.
>
> John Mattes, who ran the “San Diego for Bernie Sanders” page, said he saw a shift from familiar local commenters to newcomers, some with Eastern European names — including four different accounts using the name “Oliver Mitov.”
>
> “Those who voted for Bernie, will not vote for corrupt Hillary!” one of the Mitovs wrote on Oct. 7. “The Revolution must continue! #NeverHillary”

## Finally, it is naïve to think that Bernie would have had an easy time against Trump

From [Eichenwald's Newsweek article quoted earlier](http://www.newsweek.com/myths-cost-democrats-presidential-election-521044):

> So what would have happened when Sanders hit a real opponent, someone who did not care about alienating the young college voters in his base? I have seen the opposition book assembled by Republicans for Sanders, and it was brutal. The Republicans would have torn him apart....
>
> The Republicans had at least four other damning Sanders videos (I don’t know what they showed), and the opposition research folder was almost 2-feet thick. (The section calling him a communist with connections to Castro alone would have cost him Florida.) In other words, the belief that Sanders would have walked into the White House based on polls taken before anyone  really attacked him is a delusion built on a scaffolding of political ignorance.

[Plenty of other dirt out there on Bernie](http://www.shakesville.com/2017/03/its-past-time-for-dems-to-get-serious.html), if, like the Republicans, you want to spin it that way:

> Consider the claim that **BernieWouldaWon**. This is based on many things, but there's a base assumption that he wasn't "flawed" or "tarnished" or whatever word we are using today. That Clinton's "flaws" brought her down.
>
> Okay. Let's play "Bernie Woulda Been Flawed". How would that go down? Well, here's a few samples.
>
> 1. Bernie the Liar.
> 2. Bernie the Creepy Sex Freak.
> 3. Saunders the Stalinist.
> 4. Jane Sanders, or, Bernie's College Plan is Terrible.
> 5. Sanders the Racist Nativist
> 6. Sanders and Trump are Just the Same, but Maybe Bernie's Worse.

(Read the article for details and references for each. Remember, that author doesn't *believe* these things about Bernie, but is giving examples of how they could have been used against him.)

## EDIT: The lawsuit against the DNC was dismissed in August 2017

[Florida judge dismisses fraud lawsuit against DNC](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/powerpost/wp/2017/08/25/florida-judge-dismisses-fraud-lawsuit-against-dnc/?utm_term=.32153802e593):

> “To the extent Plaintiffs wish to air their general grievances with the DNC or its candidate selection process, their redress is through the ballot box, the DNC’s internal workings, or their right of free speech — not through the judiciary,” Judge William Zloch, a Reagan appointee, wrote in his dismissal. “To the extent Plaintiffs have asserted specific causes of action grounded in specific factual allegations, it is this Court’s emphatic duty to measure Plaintiffs’ pleadings against existing legal standards. Having done so . . . the Court finds that the named Plaintiffs have not presented a case that is cognizable in federal court.”

To be clear, the judge ruled that none of the plaintiffs had "standing", not necessarily that their claims of partiality were necessarily false:

> The complaint itself was far more narrow, and it was dismissed after Zloch ruled that the plaintiffs did not have standing. There was no evidence, the judge wrote, that anyone had donated to the DNC on the promise that the committee and its employees would be completely impartial.
>
> “Not one of them alleges that they ever read the DNC’s charter or heard the statements they now claim are false before making their donations,” Zloch wrote. “And not one of them alleges that they took action in reliance on the DNC’s charter or the statements identified in the First Amended Complaint. Absent such allegations, these Plaintiffs lack standing.”

Comment: That doesn't seem to answer the question, merely critiques its (easily editable) premise.

Comment: @user4012 The question is based on a false premise that the DNC  didn't merely *prefer* Hillary over Bernie, but that they "cheated" him out of the nomination. This answer rebuts that premise, making "why would they do such a thing" moot. It also rebuts the premise that Bernie necessarily had a better chance against Trump than Clinton did.

Comment: @user4012 I think that rejecting the premise of a question can be an answer. Note though that this answer also contains an answer to the question as-is, namely that any action the DNC may have taken was after Sanders's chance of winning was basically 0, in order to strengthen the almost certain nominee.

Comment: It's true enough that the DNC didn't literally rig the election in the sense of actually changing vote totals (just as the same is true regarding Russia in the general election,) but that doesn't mean (or even provide evidence) that they didn't work to try to prevent him from winning the primary (which is all they've been accused of and what this question explicitly asks about.) This answer is attacking a straw man. If the DNC did nothing wrong, why was its chair forced to resign?

Comment: @reirab While I agree in principle, it's on the *accusers* to prove the DNC *did* have it out for Bernie, and my post explains that the best evidence they've provided (the stolen DNC emails) doesn't actually show what they are purported to show. Regarding why the chair resigned amid the uproar, I think one word is sufficient: *politics*.

Comment: @BradC The leaked e-mails absolutely do show that they were working against Sanders, which is exactly what was purported and is what this question asks about. Whether it would have made a difference in the outcome or not is a different question. I certainly agree that it was unlikely Bernie would have been nominated in either case, but that doesn't mean that it's fair for the party itself to actively work against him.

Comment: @reirab The email dates show otherwise: you're not "working against Sanders" if the race is already over (to a mathematical certainty), you're just strategizing about how to move on from there.

Comment: A judge ruling that it has no standing, or is not illegal does not state that the claims have no factual merit. That edit also does not address the question or even the claims behind it.

Comment: IIRC Several representatives selected Clinton as their nominee despite their districts voting popularly for Sanders.  They typically used the reasoning that Sanders was not a candidate with a legitimate chance of winning, so it was in their constituents' best interests for them to go against what voters wanted and nominate Clinton anyway.  This was not "against the rules" but I think many have argued it is against the spirit of American democracy.  Whether the story was picked up by Russian propagandists is not relevant to that argument.  Since primaries didn't happen all at once, a few early

Comment: ... Sanders defeats as a result of these elector's choices created a situation in which the popular assessment of Sanders' chance of victory continued to plummet (and make headlines) in the run up to subsequent primaries, creating a snowball effect where more people didn't even bother to vote for Sanders who otherwise might have.  He was popularly dismissed as a candidate well before his chances of victory were actually gone.  That whole particular situation could have been averted if all primaries happened nationwide on the same day.

Comment: This isn't a fact based answer, it's a political argument referencing both opinion pieces and applying an opinionated interpretation on primary sources (where there are alternate interpretations that can be just as easily argued).  StackExchange is not built for this sort of thing.  I could easily write a post, taking this point for point, referencing sources of equivalent quality, refuting your arguments.  But it doesn't fit in a StackExchange comment.  This sort of exchange is not what this platform was built for.

Comment: @Darren That's how superdelegates work.   Clinton also has 12% higher vote count.  55% to 43% votes isn't very close.    I think this answer is highly relevant and people are saying it isn't because they don't want to hear it.   It's easy to assume the worst, but that doesn't make it always true.   That's not to say that the DNC acted admirably.  .   because I don't think they did, but claims of rigging and fixing seem highly overblown.

Comment: @userLTK I don't disagree with you there, but IMHO it seems at least slightly unfair how some seem to accuse anyone with criticism of the DNC as effectively buying into Russian propaganda.  It's true that many seem to be repeating unsubstantiated or fabricated claims rather than making coherent arguments, but I'm afraid there isn't really any issue these days that isn't overblown and surrounded by misinterpretations of limited and/or adversarial information.

Comment: @Darren I understand how "buying into Russian propaganda" seems hyperbolic, and there was clearly already a divide between groups on the left, but it is factual that the Russians were the source of the email hack, AND the source of the strategically-timed release, AND the source of the initial characterization of these emails as damning to the DNC (which they weren't, upon proper analysis). Yes, the media loves a controversy, and Bernie supporters and Trump supporters jumped on board because it supported their pre-existing views, but Russian bots also continued to keep this alive.

Comment: @BradC I think those are all great points. I just felt it was worth pointing out that some (many of whom even voted for Clinton in the general election) have been critical of the DNC and its treatment of Bernie Sanders since before the email leaks even happened - as I saw it this was a sore point that propagandists were able to exploit.  Your answer seems appropriate for the question as it was worded in the text, which is highly referential to the leaked emails, but the way the question is titled may be what's leading some to claim this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Darren I agree with much of that, the DNC is certainly not above criticism. I do focus on a different aspect of the question than user4012's excellent answer, but I think it is important to address the elephant in the room. With the "corrupt Hillary" narrative overshadowing everything, it can be difficult to distinguish between Russian propaganda, butt-hurt from Bernie fans, and more subtle (and valid) questions about the role and actions of the DNC.

Comment: @Darren I think assumptions of collusion are very much the same and I agree with your point I think.  We know Russia was involved, ofcourse, but that doesn't prove collusion on the part of the Trump campaign, so I agree with you there.   Lots of people are quick to assume the worst about the candidate they don't like and we shouldn't do that.  We should look at the evidence.   And I certainly didn't mean to imply the DNC behaved properly, and I don't think the person who answered this question did either.  But there's a large chasm between improper behavior and rigging a primary.

Comment: Donna Brazile: "I found 'proof' the DNC rigged the nomination for Hillary Clinton." Your answer is not really relevant or factual.

Comment: @MultiMike Despite the "shocking" (read: "book selling") headlines, the [joint fundraising pact with the Clinton campaign](https://www.politico.com/story/2015/08/dnc-democratic-committee-hillary-clinton-fundraising-agreement-2016-121813) was known in 2015, as was [*Bernie's own* fundraising agreement with the DNC](https://www.politico.com/story/2015/11/bernie-sanders-2016-fundraising-dnc-215559). Still nothing illegal, improper, or "rigged' about it.

Comment: How do you derive the claim that Bernie's primary chances were *not* rigged from the claim that the evidence that the primary was rigged was stolen? Stolen evidence (while illegal) is not propaganda regardless of who stole it.  Evidence can only be propaganda if it's fabricated. No one has ever made a claim that the evidence that the primary was rigged was fabricated.

Comment: @userLTK, Clinton did not have a higher vote count at the time the superdelegates committed. Their commitment (used as a pretext for saying that she locked the nomination) was used  as a campaign point to secure a higher vote count.

Comment: @grovkin Clinton won most of the early states.  She got off to an early lead, and super-delegates are life-long democrats.   I understand why a Bernie supporter might object, but super-delegates have been casting their votes for candidates in primary elections for as long as there have been voting booths.   "Rigged" seems a strong word when the same approach was used in 2016 as was done in 2008 and 2004 and 2000 and 1992 and 1988 and . . . you get the idea.   Did you cry foul over super-delegates when they helped Obama claim victory over Hillary in 2008?  If not, you're a hypocrite.

Comment: @ulerLTK Democratic party was reporting superdelegate count as part of the count of delegates won in primary elections for a while before Clinton actually had a substantial lead.  In fact, even during the convention, had all the superdelegates switched to Bernie, Bernie would have won.  So her primary lead was *not* overwhelming.  In fact, I think before the NY primary (April 16th) she was neck-in-neck or even losing in the delegate count resulting from the primaries.  But all the reports always included superdelegate count.  This created the impression that she was the preferred candidate.

Comment: @grovkin I would add to that, Bernie knew about super-delegates going in.    It wasn't like they were created to sabotage him.   They were always there.   It was his job to try to win them over.   He KNEW that going in.    Just as he knew he'd have to win the black vote from Hillary - which he fumbled.   I like Bernie.   I really do, but Bernie knew, going in, as an independent joining and running as a democrat, that the supers would probably be against him.   Turning that into some kind of conspiracy theory and rigged election is just bonkers.

Comment: @userLTK, No one said that his primary was sabotaged in the way the votes were counted or the way the procedure was handled.  The claim, and the ONLY claim is that the Democratic party torpedoed his primary with its *messaging*.  This is the ONLY accusation against the Democratic party.  But it is substantial.  Because the party was torpedoing him *while it still formally claimed to be committed to being neutral*.

Comment: @grovkin   Iowa was a virtual tie (I'm of the opinion that the casual Iowa format doesn't mean much).  Sanders won NH but he's from Vermont.   Clinton won Nevada and South Carolina.   After that came Super Tuesday which Clinton won 8 states to 4.  (or 7 to 4 if we throw out Samoa).   After super Tuesday she had 10 wins to Bernie's 5.   I don't see what you see in the early primary elections.    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Results_of_the_Democratic_Party_presidential_primaries,_2016#Iowa  Yes the supers made her lead bigger, but she came out of the gate wining.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76481/discussion-between-userltk-and-grovkin).

Comment: @userLTK you are still arguing with a point that no one made.  No one said that Bernie won the election.  Only that the Democratic party worked to sabotage his chances while it still claimed to be neutral.  That's the only claim.

Comment: @grovkin please use chat.   The Mods are likely to delete and comments aren't for back and forth.   Also, you're reading things that I didn't say.   I responded to your use of the word rigged and your statement that Hillary wasn't ahead.   I did nothing more than address your claims.

Comment: Are you really citing Kurt Eichenwald? The hentai connoisseur?

Answer (score 25):

It should also be mentioned that Bernie Sanders is not a Democrat.  He ran for the Senate as an [independent](https://www.facebook.com/berniesanders/posts/1167698526618483).  While he caucused with the Democrats, he never claimed to be one before running for president.  For that matter, while running he barely claimed to be a Democrat.  He [joined party leadership](http://www.politico.com/story/2016/11/independent-bernie-sanders-democratic-leadership-231486), but now he's back to [declaring himself an independent](http://thehill.com/homenews/campaign/329418-sanders-i-do-not-consider-myself-a-democrat).

Is it any surprise that Democratic party partisans (which is what the Democratic National Committee is) did not want Sanders to win their nomination?

It's also worth noting that prior to the primaries, Sanders was considered a joke candidate.  Sanders didn't seem particularly serious about running for president.  He skipped the prep jobs, like raising money for other candidates.  A number of times he said that he wanted to see changes from the party.  Why would the DNC, which helped set the party platform, want to help him change it?

For example, here's an excerpt from an early story by [CNN](http://www.cnn.com/2015/04/29/politics/bernie-sanders-announces-presidential-run/index.html):

> Sanders is a dark horse candidate and has acknowledged that his run will be uphill. A CNN/ORC poll in March found that Sanders has the support of only 3% of Democratic voters.

Back then, even progressives were looking for other candidates.  For example, the same CNN story had

> "MoveOn members welcome Sen. Bernie Sanders to the presidential race," said Galland. "The Democratic Party is made stronger by each additional voice who enters the race and commits to being a strong advocate for everyday, hardworking Americans and not just the wealthy few. That's why we and our allies continue to call on Sen. Elizabeth Warren to also bring her tireless advocacy for middle-class and working Americans to the race. Our country will be stronger if she runs."

At that time, even his natural supporters were looking for a better candidate.  Meanwhile, Hillary Clinton had courted her natural supporters for years.  She convinced potentially better candidates like Joe Biden and Elizabeth Warren to stay out.  She had endorsements and funding lined up and waiting for her.  On paper, she seemed the stronger candidate.

Now, in reality, we know that she lost.  To Donald Trump, the most unpopular winner ever.  But people didn't know that in 2015 and early 2016.  And realize that they did know her.  She had been active in Democratic causes and worked with many of the DNC people for years.  Sanders ignored the DNC until he ran for president.

Comment: One thing this answer doesn't get into is that most of those "damning" emails happened after Sanders had any legit chance to win the primary. What the DNC staffers were trying to do was end a primary race that could no longer have any effect but hurt their nominee. They did the exact same thing *against* Clinton in 2008.

Answer (score 14):

The basic mechanism of a political party is to reward loyalty and create a unified front. Clinton had some 40+ years of favors to call in from various democrats, and anybody in the party who threw in for her could expect some obligation if/when she finally won.

Meanwhile Bernie was an independent his whole political career and not a member of the democratic party. Nobody in the democratic party owed him anything, nor vice-versa. The only relationship he had with the Democratic party is that he caucused with them in the Senate (he sat in on their private meetings).

So from the perspective of an average Democratic party member, here was an outsider coming in to hijack their party and platform to put himself up as president, when they had a candidate they had been working on for the past 15 years. Clinton's Senate tenure was in preparation for her 2008 run, and after Obama (who came up through the democratic party system) won, her being Secretary of State was further preparation for another run. It was basically Clinton's turn, from the insider perspective. Sanders had never done anything for the Democratic party.

On top of that, Clinton had incredible name recognition, and the DNC already knew what kind of attacks republicans would try against her. Sanders was a virtual unknown on the national stage, until he ran for president. They didn't know what kind of attacks would be run on him, or what skeletons from his past would be dug up. Clinton was a known quantity, a much safer bet, and political parties are inherently conservative.

As others have pointed out, the DNC didn't pull anything really underhanded or illegal for Sanders not to win, but it should be no surprise that the establishment didn't support him. They supported the candidate they had been preparing for the past decade and a half.

**Edit**  The bottom of the meme makes the claim that the DNC (Democratic National Committee) is "supposedly ... a neutral party". This is just plain wrong. Nobody but the ignorant and politically naive suppose it to be a neutral party.

First off, as a political party it's a private organization, in every sense of the phrase, just like, say, a business, a men's club, or a church. They can do whatever they damn please. That being said, they do have an interest in attracting as wide a membership as possible, since their ostensible goal is to win elections.

In other words, political parties are private organizations, and don't have any duty or obligation to be transparent, democratic, fair, etc. They don't owe American citizens anything. They are not set up by the US constitution like the Congress or Presidency is. They are not answerable to anybody except their own members.

Second, they're not neutral. The point of a political party is to win power, not provide a platform for anyone who wants to run, or a level playing field for candidates to spar. They have a vested interest in winning. They could play as many dirty, unfair, or biased tricks as they want, so long as they aren't breaking the law.

Comment: This is a nice, rational answer.

Comment: "First off, as a political it's a private organization". I think there is a word missing here. Possibly you meant to write "political party"?

Comment: I'd note that Smith v. Allwright (1944) was a Supreme Court case saying the Democratic Party in Texas did not have the right to have an all-white primary, prior to any voting rights legislation at the federal level. I don't know about the current Supreme Court, but the way the two parties have tangled themselves into our political system makes me think that similar rulings, restricting them more than a business or men's club, might be possible. (Which doesn't negate the core point there.)

Answer (score 8):

The premise that he was "prevented" from winning is a little misguided, he simply never had support. By no metric was he ever close to even being the most popular Democrat politician, let alone general politician.

Compare the [2016 Democratic elections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Democratic_Party_presidential_primaries,_2016) against the [2008 elections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Democratic_Party_presidential_primaries,_2008), in which Hillary and Obama were within 100,000 votes of each other - *very close*. However, in 2016, Bernie was well over three million votes short of Hillary. His popularity was strong in some vocal urban districts,  whose members might have been active on social media - but he never enjoyed widespread support from the rest of the party.

Comment: The question doesn't seem to be about if he was a good or viable candidate, (though that could be part of an answer) it asks why (if) the DNC took steps to influence the primary against him. I would think being hopeless makes it weirder to interfere, certainly they didn't put effort into undermining Mickie Mouse.

Comment: OP started from the presumption that Bernie was a better candidate, and if DNC leadership had acted differently, Bernie might have been a viable candidate. But that's working off flawed assumptions. I have to set us back to first principles (_did_ the DNC take action against Bernie? Was it unusual? Can we trust the source? etc) before we can have a meaningful discussion (which will have to take place in other threads, since those are much different questions).

Comment: That doesn't seem to answer the question, merely critiques its (easily editable) premise.

Comment: I'd rather answer OP's premise instead of edit it out. They asked a question and included that they believed Bernie to be a more viable candidate - the other things that were asked flowed directly from this assumption. We can't truly answer OP without explaining that this original assumption simply isn't true.

Comment: While I agree that refuting the OP's premise is a valid answer, I think the claim that he "never had support" is a gross overstatement.  13.2 million vs 16.9 million isn't an indication of "no support" (see BradC's answer). Not to mention that polls had him at similar levels when pitted against republican candidates as Hillary.

Comment: Part of the accusation is that Sanders, being a low-recognition outsider, was fatally crippled by the DNC basically putting a media blackout on all events with the major candidates side by side. Sanders' popularity was on par with Hillary as he gained more name recognition, ***after*** those early primary contests were already decided. It's circular to say "they didn't tilt the results.... see, his results were poor from the start!" All that says, potentially, is that they succeeded in doing so at the very start.

Comment: Sanders started at less than 2 or 3 percent with almost zero recognition. To get where he did indicates huge success, and also suggests more exposure, early, would have made a difference.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet true though...look at the GOP races. There seems to be an increasing amount of 'random luck' in the modern era when it comes to presidential primary races. Seems even a change in weather can influence things.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet Obama was also a fringe candidate who started with no name recognition or broad support. It seems strange to say that Bernie losing by so much is proof that he was popular among Democrats, whereas Obama (running on a similar platform) was able to best _exactly the same opponent_ 8 years earlier. By every metric, Clinton did _better_ in 2016 than in 2008 during the party primaries - she simply was more popular for the entire candidacy.
https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/bernie-sanders-youre-no-barack-obama/

Comment: It's pretty clear you didn't actually read my comment, entirely, or try to understand what I was saying. Before and after polling is relevant to the claims that Sanders had about skewing results, but it doesn't change the vote count, so nice job ignoring the entire reason why I brought it up and just repeating what you originally wrote.

Comment: I'm trying to help you understand that you're ignoring how Clinton performed and focusing solely on Bernie. Anyone could claim that the election was rigged against their favorite candidate and wave away the polls, election results, districts and data - but that's a position born of faith rather than anything concrete. That's why I gave you that last link - to illustrate that in 2016 Clinton simply performed much better than in 2008 - by every poll and metric. I may be trying to use too much evidence to do that, but i'm hoping some of it will stick and you might later look back at it honestly.

Comment: Focusing on how Bernie performed does not ignore how Clinton performed. They are entirely related to each other.  I have no idea what you're talking about when you write that. I'm not waving away results, I'm pointing out the nature of each's candidacy, the specific allegations involved, the voting results, their polling, and how they relate. I'm the only one looking at specific context in our discussion.

Comment: If Sanders has little name recognition, Clinton has a lot, and a commensurate lead that reflects that, and Sanders claims that the DNC is trying to suppress all candidate exposure, who would that hurt or favor more? And if we see that Clinton had a huge margin in early states, but, as Sanders name recognition grew, the polling in those states drastically changed, would that not support the contention that suppression hurt one candidate over another? If we have further, unrefuted documentation that the DNC did this, is that not more relevant than "she won that primary." Yes, but why and how?

Answer (score 4):

If we go back to the start of the 2016 campaign, which was really in the spring of 2015, Hillary Clinton was the presumptive nominee. At that time, the scandals that later beset her were not yet headline material. The Democrats who could have been competitive: Biden, Schumer, Cuomo, etc... had chosen not to challenge her.

The dems were most concerned about losing the 2016 election, having lost both the house and senate in the previous six years, indicating that the mood of the nation was swinging to the right of center. The last thing the DNC wanted was to have a populist candidate pushing the campaign platform further to the left. They fully expected to be facing a conventional centrist or right of center repub candidate in 2016, in a conventional campaign, with the mood of the nation swinging to the right, judging by voting patterns.

Bernie Sanders was a left leaning independent senator, running a quixotic campaign that no one expected to achieve any real level of support. It is likely that the DNC worked to undermine him to keep him from steering the debate and the platform to the left.

Remember, this was the view in early to mid 2015 - how naive that seems now.

By the time of the convention, Clinton scandals were front page news and her contrite answers simply made her look even more guilty, while the repubs had somehow ended up a boorish political neophyte as their prime candidate, and Sanders was polling higher than Clinton and Trump in the main election. In the main election, it now appears that a lot of Sanders supporters simply didn't vote at all, aghast at the shoddy way their candidate had been treated. They couldn't vote for the ogre, and wouldn't vote for the backstabber.

So the move to torpedo Sanders turned out to be a major blunder, especially after that move became obvious. Long before the purloined emails were released, the DNC had scheduled the primary debates during off viewing hours, presumably to limit coverage of Sanders The DNC at one point cut the Sanders campaign off from their voter information database as someone in the Sanders campaign had gotten into the Clinton campaign's private information. That person turned out to be an admin who had been recommended to the Sanders campaign by DNC chair Debbie Schultz. It seems the DNC chair sent a mole into the Sanders campaign to sabotage it.

Combined with the 'super delegates', selected by the party and not the voters, this made the DNC look like they had no interest in what the electorate thought. Back room politics at its worst.

The 2016 US presidential election was certainly one of the strangest on record.

Comment: This is the common conspiracy theory but is mostly hyperbole. That said, I can't argue with your conclusion. :)

Comment: Only if you don't like the conclusion. The democratic party did try to sink Sanders so they wouldn't get another McGovern situation, and they didn't plan on their anointed choice having so many problems emerge as the campaign went on. Ironically, the dems meddled in their primary when they shouldn't, while the repubs didn't meddle in their primary and perhaps they should have.

Comment: I'm rather indifferent to the whole situation. From all the data I've seen, though, Sanders didn't really have a chance within the party. There's no doubt he had very *vocal* followers, they just weren't in the numbers he really needed. I think it's very fair to say the party *preferred* Clinton, but to say they *torpedoed* Sanders is, IMHO, hyperbole.

Answer (score 1):

There are two questions here: 1) Did the DNC try to prevent Sanders from winning the nomination, and 2) If in fact they did, why?

I can't speak to the first question, not having evidence, but it seems reasonable that they might have.  If they did, the why seems pretty obvious: they wanted a Democratic candidate who stood a reasonable chance of winning the election.  Leftist candidates, or those seen as such, are not popular with the American electorate.   We have to go back quite a ways to find a candidate as far to the left as Sanders, all the way to George McGovern in 1972.  The result was that Nixon carried 49 states, McGovern only Massachusetts, the second most lopsided election since WWII: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_presidential_election,_1972

Comment: Except that, even as Hillary was in the home stretch of wrapping up the nomination, back then, she was polling even or a point or two behind Trump in head to head polling, while Sanders was polling well ahead of Trump.  So, as far as "reasonable chance," Sanders was actually a better matchup. If they match up, since Sanders is also a populist outsider, in the eyes of the public, he doesn't automatically lose the "establishment vs populist" votes like Hillary did.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet: Which polls?  I certainly don't recall seeing any.  As for Sanders being a "populist", we must be using very different definitions of the word.  His appeal seemed limited to the leftist elite and naive youth.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet I don't recall that being the case but even if it was, it really doesn't mean anything...as Hillary was the candidate, so was taking the full brunt of any attacks. Just because an also-ran was polling high at that time doesn't mean they'd have done any better under direct attack from the opponent.

Comment: @jamesqf - yes, we must have very different definition. For example, Trumps populist appeal can be said to be limited to racists and xenophobes, if we want to play that game. Which polls? Here's a fact-check on Sanders' claims to that effect - http://www.politifact.com/truth-o-meter/statements/2016/may/29/bernie-s/bernie-sanders-says-he-polls-better-against-donald/

Comment: "Leftist candidates, or those seen as such, are not popular with the American electorate." I don't see how you can know that, seeing that "leftist" (not a word I'm fond of) candidates are rare in US politics.

Comment: @Faheem Mitha: Perhaps the reason they're rare is that most potential candidates know they have little chance of winning, at least if they express their views openly.

Comment: You have not only evidence, you have outright admission in the leaked Podesta emails, and a detailed description of how things work in the Donna Brazile book. But, more importantly, if the Democratic Party leadership had wanted the candidate with a better chance to beat Trump, they would have definitely supported Sanders; he was leading Trump in the polls more than Clinton, and did not have the horrible public image of Clinton. So, -1.

Comment: @einpoklum Sanders didn't have the horrible public image of Clinton because Hlilary Clinton, knowing she could win the primary, played softball with him to not lose his supporters. Had the Republican party turned the big guns on him, "Sanders went to the Soviet Union and trashed the US" and "Sanders proposed shipping nuclear waste to a poor Hispanic town" and other true facts, presented in the most hostile manner, would have shredded his public image.